# Xcode 4.4 App icon not working

Tags: xcode, icons

I was following this tutorial:

```
http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=28&number=3
```

It says that there is a resource folder, but here in Xcode 4.4 there is no resource folder. How can I set an icon? I've been trying since 4 hours nothing works.. I've put 57x57 png image file in  "Supporting Files" folder as directed by the guy :(

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your icon example icon.png 57x57 pixel and icon@2x.png 114x114 pixel for retina display
Open your app, at the left you see Project panel (or set it from menu View > Navigators > Sho Project Navigator), click on name of your Project, at right you see Project and Targets, click on nome in Targets list > Summary tab, in Iphone / iPod deployment Info you see two App Icons box, drag icon.png from folder to first box, and icon@2x.png on second box (for Retina display), you did it!

Files are automatically added to .plist file, infact if you go at Project panel at the left, open Supporting files folder > YourNameApp-Info.plist, you found key Info files (iOS5) > Primary icon > Icon files and Item 0 =icon.png and Item1 = icon@2x.png